# How to set a header (specifically cookie) in the response of a Worklight Adapter Procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

It's obvious how to set headers accessing a backend system via invokeHttp method, but I can't for the life of my find a way to write a cookie or even write a response header in the response back from the adapter procedure.  I'd like to be able to write a Set-Cookie header in the HTTP response back to the client.  I also want this to be a true HTTP header, not just part of the JSON body.

Comment: Just in case there's a work-around we can think of, why do you need to do this? From the client's view, the fact that this is an HTTP request is hidden. Perhaps you have some network cleverness in mind?

Comment: Based on the backend response, we're trying to set a Set-Cookie header that's used by some network appliances for some security and correlation tasks for subsequent requests.

I believe our work around solution will be to send the data back and the response JSON body and have the client JavaScript set the cookie.

Comment: I can understand that requirement, and your solution seems viable, but slightly annoying as every client must remember to do this. So this does seem to emphasise the need for the Feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Worklight. We do have a feature request for it, though, so it may happen some day...

Feel free to add an additional feature request to highlight the need for it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Comment: [Request For Enhancement: Ability to set custom cookies in HTTP adapter for responses to Client App](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=56068)